# Adding data at the specific position of Listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a listview and I have to add two more element in listview. I have to add notifyDataSetChanged() . but not sure how to do it.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter (this, sourceList);
listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`sourceList` is the `List` .

I need to add 2 items at the end of the Listview. Thanks.

Comment: add data to source list and use `myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: first add data to list in every position that you want then calling `myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your desired data to the adapter. For example:

```
myListAdapter.add(obj1);
```

The newly added data will be attached at the end of your `ListView`.

Remember: when injecting data directly into an `Adapter`, you don't need to call its `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

If you modify your `sourceList` object, in that case its necessary to call `notifyDataSetChanged` method in order for the `Adapter` to refresh its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Dummy Example to add the adapter to the List.

Read the Comment

```
ListView lstViewtodo; //Your ListView

List<NoteModel> list_note_model = new ArrayList<NoteModel>(); // for Adding the Array of your Model 

NoteModel noteModel = new NoteModel(txttitle, jsonArray, obj.getUid(), txtColorType, false); //Your Model

list_note_model.add(0, noteModel); //Adding the value to array

lstViewtodo.setAdapter(list); //finally adding the content to list
```

**To Add the Content Dynamically...**

```
NoteListAdapter list = new NoteListAdapter( NoteMainActivity.this , R.layout.todo_adapter_view , list_note_model); //Your class extending the ArrayAdapter<NoteModel>

    NoteModel noteModel = new NoteModel(txttitle, jsonArray, obj.getUid(), txtColorType, false);'

    list_note_model.add(0, noteModel);

list.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Let me Know if You Difficulty...